# jquery get var from uri

Tags: jquery, url, variables, uri

I have two page page1.php and page2.php, on page1.php i click on a href and that link to page2.php somewhere...

in the page2.php there is 4 expander, hidden or close on pageload...

question : i like to pass from page 1 to page2 which of the expander i like to see OPEN

something like page1 href="page2.php?open=1"

and on page2.php a jquery that retreive the open var, and after pageload expand only that one...

i have research google and come with that : https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

is it possible to do that without plugsin ?

Comment: I've never used php, but can you not get the uri components on your server page (int open = request.params["open"]) for example and then just link it in the client page with tags <%=open%>

Comment: i have done it in php $_GET['var'] and injet it into java... work great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific answer:

```
var expanderNo = (location.search.match(/open=(\d+)/) || [])[1]
```

But if your intention here is to link to a specific part of the page, then [URL fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) is more appropriate. Given the URL `/page2.php#expander1` you can retrieve the `expander1` part with `location.hash.substr(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one generic way of doing it, probably not the best, but I had the code on hand, so thought I'd share.

```
    function getVars(){
        var vars = new Array();
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var parms = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parms.length; i++) {
                var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
                if (pos > 0) {
                        var key = parms[i].substring(0, pos);
                        var val = parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
                        vars[key] = val;
                }else{
                        return Array();
                }
        }
        return vars;
   }
```

it will return a key value pair for each parameter.

The other answer (Alexey's) is better if you know the parameters beforehand.

Comment: A typo in parms.length, and the function will return prematurely given  a string 'foo=1&bar&baz=2'. Instead of 'No Variables Found' you can simply return an empty array.

Comment: Edited. 

You're right. In my case it worked for all the conditions that applied, i.e. `&bar` was an impossible scenario.